# Error in Office Outlook Add-in during Initiallzation

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins

I get an error as this when loading my Outlook add-in in the Desktop client:

```
SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function.
```

My initialization code looks something like this:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    app.initialize();

    // set adal.js b2c authentication
    setAuthContext();

    // handle any window callback redirections
    authContext.handleWindowCallback();

    checkUser();
    setListeners();
};
```

I tried different variations with the initialize function of Office.js but I get the same error over and over again. This doesn't happen with the same outlook add-in in Outlook online.

Am I doing something wrong with the Office app initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use   *$(document).ready* or *window.onload*  and then set your code.

From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office):

> If you are using additional JavaScript frameworks that include their own initialization handler or tests, these should be placed within the Office.initialize event. For example, JQuery's $(document).ready()

code:

```
Office.initialize = function () {
// Office is ready
$(document).ready(function () {        
    // The document is ready insert your code here

});
};
```

Comment: @immysl If you write just this and set something simple like set 'hello world' in the compose window it's still have error , I mean without your functions..?

Comment: @immysl It's strange , Can you share little bit more ? from where you run it ?Vs? and little bit more code... tnx

Comment: It was actually an error just before the initialization code that was causing this problem. Soon as I fixed that the initialization code started to work. Anyway thanks a lot for your help :) I'll mark your answer as the correct one, since it does fix the real initialization issues which wasn't the case with mine.

Comment: Happy to hear that you fix the problem and happy to hear that I help a little. Good luck :)